# What is the point of @WebInitParam?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

@WebInitParam is an annotation that goes at class level.
It defines initialization parameters for the servlet.

I would like to know, what is the difference between doing this and using static variables, and why do it the @WebInitParam way rather than using statics?

What does defining k/v pairs as @WebInitParams allow you to do that you couldn't do if you declared static variables instead?

I have looked and all I can find is a million people saying how to define @WebInitParams. Well yes that's the easy bit. It's what I can do with that that is really what is of interest.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Often filters and such you can pull in jars are configured via web params

Answer (score 4):

**From a "raison d'etre" perspective**, the annotation exists as a better design and architecture alternative to just peppering a class with static fields. `@WebInitParam` is a self-documenting approach to the initialization parameters a servlet or filter class needs, available via web.xml as well. It serves this purpose for the end developers as well as the JavaEE platform as a whole.

Think about it this way: in a vanilla project, you have the option of hardcoding a bunch of parameters in the class as static fields, or defining the same parameters in a property file. Which would you pick? Under what circumstances?

**From a purely functional angle,** apart from the function of [using the annotation to override defaults set in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064518/use-cases-for-webinitparam), one other major reason is that you will sometimes need to get a hold of those initialization parameters from another component in your application. Using the annotation essentially increases the visibility of the parameter. In JSF for example, the API allows you to retrieve FacesServlet initialization parameters with:

```
 //get all the parameters
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap()

//get a specific parameter 
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("aParameter");
```

In JSF-2.3 , it gets even more convenient with the following CDI-enabled injection:

```
 @InitParameterMap Map<String,String> servletParameterMap;
```

Bear in mind that because it's CDI, it means this facility is available throughout the JavaEE platform, not just in web applications/JSF.

It's going to be a hassle to retrieve init parameters if the only mechanism available is a static field in the servlet class - you'll need to obtain an instance of the filter or servlet to get the static fields in it.

Separately, one could make the argument that maybe one should favour context-params over servlet-params because then, you get even more flexibility that isn't tied to any given servlet. That's a separate matter entirely :)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the lengthy answer, but I still don't understand the use case.  Unfortunately your answer like many others explains in terms of code syntax but doesn't say, "this is why you might use it". My understanding of servlets etc is limited (I only started learning a few weeks ago). What I'm getting at is, if you had say a simple JSP page that called a servlet page that called a service bean (EJB), what would having @WebInitParams defined in the servlet allow you to do that you could not do with static fields instead?  Thanks.

Comment: If you mean what does it do for the individual servlet? Nothing that you can't achieve with a static field. But good design and best practice looks beyond the individual class involved and looks at the whole application and platform. From a broader, more holistic perspective, the initparam is the best way to go. It's like the choice between hard coding variables in a class versus extracting them into a properties file: sure they effectively work the same way but one is objectively better design than the other @JL_SO

Comment: I think I see. I think what you are saying is that static fields can contain anything, for any purpose, but webinitparams are self-documented as being fields whose purpose is to provide init params for the servlet, so any developer maintaining the code can see them clearly without having to scan amongst static fields that might be for any purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Very well put yourself @JL_SO